# Why am I, inadvertently, scaling an image while slicing it into 'tiles' using `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, drawimage

For no particular reason, other than a lack of familiarity with the `canvas`, and `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()`, I tried to write a function that would take an `<image>` element and other options, such as the number of 'rows' and 'cols' into which that `<image>` should be 'sliced'.

Currently, as a first step this should transfer the 'sliced' image-portions into a created `<canvas>` element appended to the `document`.

While this function sort of works – provided I don't change the default number of rows and columns – the result is, nevertheless cropped for some reason, for example this source image:

[image]

Is scaled to this:

[image]

I fully accept this is likely down to confusion in my application of maths, and almost certainly has to be within the `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()` and thus probably lies within the `for` loop but having stared at it, and taken a number of coffee breaks, I'm not yet seeing where my silliness lies.

A snippet of my code:

```js
// Using ES6/ECMAScript 2015 'let' operator

function imageFragment(opts) {
  // defaults for the function (to be overridden)
  // by user supplied values (if any are passed):
  let settings = {
    'source': document.querySelector('img'),
    'rows': 2,
    'cols': 2,
    'trim': true
  };

  // Using Object.keys to retrieve the keys of the
  // opts Object, or an empty object (without keys)
  // should no opts Object be supplied;
  // using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over
  // the Array of keys, using Arrow syntax, to
  // update the defaults settings to the user-defined
  // settings:
  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(key => settings[key] = opts[key]);

  let image = settings.source,
    frame = document.createElement('div'),
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    imageHeight = image.clientHeight,
    imageWidth = image.clientWidth,
    tileHeight = parseInt(imageHeight / settings.rows, 10),
    tileWidth = parseInt(imageWidth / settings.cols, 10),
    // following two variables, heightRemainder and
    // widthRemainder, are not currently used, but here
    // in anticipation of settings.trim being set to 'false':
    heightRemainder = imageHeight % tileHeight,
    widthRemainder = imageWidth % tileWidth,
    nCols = settings.cols + (settings.trim === true ? 0 : 1),
    nRows = settings.rows + (settings.trim === true ? 0 : 1),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // updating properties of the frame and canvas
  // element nodes:
  frame.classList.add('canvasWrapper');
  canvas.style.width = nCols * tileWidth + 'px';
  canvas.style.height = nRows * tileHeight + 'px';
  canvas.classList.add('tile');

  // using nested for loops to iterate over each of
  // the 'columns' within each 'row' (I strongly
  // believe this could be revised, and hopefully
  // simplified):
  for (let r = 0; r < nRows; r++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < nCols; c++) {

      // defining the section of the image to copy,
      // image: the source image,
      // (r * tileWidth): the x-offset position of
      // the upper-left corner of the 'segment' to
      // copy on this iteration,
      // (c * tileHeight): the y-offset position of
      // the upper-left corner of the 'segment',
      // tileWidth: the width of the 'segment' to copy,
      // tilleHeight: the height of the 'segment' to copy,
      // (r * tileWidth): the target horizontal position of the
      // upper-left corner of the copied 'segment' in
      // the target (the canvas),
      // (c * tileHeight): the target vertical position of
      // the upper-left corner of the copied 'segment' in the
      // target,
      // tileWidth and tileHeight: the width and height of
      // the copied segment in the target:
      context.drawImage(image, (r * tileWidth), (c * tileHeight), tileWidth, tileHeight, (r * tileWidth), (c * tileHeight), tileWidth, tileHeight);
    }
  }

  // appending the canvas to the frame:
  frame.appendChild(canvas);
  // inserting the frame ahead of the image within
  // the image's parentNode:
  image.parentNode.insertBefore(frame, image);
}

imageFragment({
  'rows': 3
});
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pii7e.jpg" />
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/0tug9aru/).

And, in advance of speculation, the classic face-palm was chosen deliberately for this question but replicates, exactly, the problem with the 'original' source image.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the canvas sizes. Currently, you are only resizing the default 300x150 size with CSS.

```
canvas.width = imageWidth;
canvas.height = imageHeight;
```

And then you shouldn't force `{rows: 3}`.

```js
// Using ES6/ECMAScript 2015 'let' operator

function imageFragment(opts) {
  // defaults for the function (to be overridden)
  // by user supplied values (if any are passed):
  let settings = {
    'source': document.querySelector('img'),
    'rows': 2,
    'cols': 2,
    'trim': true
  };

  // Using Object.keys to retrieve the keys of the
  // opts Object, or an empty object (without keys)
  // should no opts Object be supplied;
  // using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over
  // the Array of keys, using Arrow syntax, to
  // update the defaults settings to the user-defined
  // settings:
  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(key => settings[key] = opts[key]);

  let image = settings.source,
    frame = document.createElement('div'),
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    imageHeight = image.clientHeight,
    imageWidth = image.clientWidth,
    tileHeight = parseInt(imageHeight / settings.rows, 10),
    tileWidth = parseInt(imageWidth / settings.cols, 10),
    // following two variables, heightRemainder and
    // widthRemainder, are not currently used, but here
    // in anticipation of settings.trim being set to 'false':
    heightRemainder = imageHeight % tileHeight,
    widthRemainder = imageWidth % tileWidth,
    nCols = settings.cols + (settings.trim === true ? 0 : 1),
    nRows = settings.rows + (settings.trim === true ? 0 : 1),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // updating properties of the frame and canvas
  // element nodes:
  frame.classList.add('canvasWrapper');
  canvas.width = imageWidth;
  canvas.height = imageHeight;
  canvas.style.width = nCols * tileWidth + 'px';
  canvas.style.height = nRows * tileHeight + 'px';
  canvas.classList.add('tile');

  // using nested for loops to iterate over each of
  // the 'columns' within each 'row' (I strongly
  // believe this could be revised, and hopefully
  // simplified):
  for (let r = 0; r < nRows; r++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < nCols; c++) {
      
      // defining the section of the image to copy,
      // image: the source image,
      // (r * tileWidth): the x-offset position of
      // the upper-left corner of the 'segment' to
      // copy on this iteration,
      // (c * tileHeight): the y-offset position of
      // the upper-left corner of the 'segment',
      // tileWidth: the width of the 'segment' to copy,
      // tilleHeight: the height of the 'segment' to copy,
      // (r * tileWidth): the target horizontal position of the
      // upper-left corner of the copied 'segment' in
      // the target (the canvas),
      // (c * tileHeight): the target vertical position of
      // the upper-left corner of the copied 'segment' in the
      // target,
      // tileWidth and tileHeight: the width and height of
      // the copied segment in the target:
      context.drawImage(image, (r * tileWidth), (c * tileHeight), tileWidth, tileHeight, (r * tileWidth), (c * tileHeight), tileWidth, tileHeight);
    }
  }

  // appending the canvas to the frame:
  frame.appendChild(canvas);
  // inserting the frame ahead of the image within
  // the image's parentNode:
  image.parentNode.insertBefore(frame, image);
}

imageFragment({
  // 'rows' : 3
});
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/iWKad22m.jpg" />
```

Comment: While that works, the answer of "*[don't] force `{rows: 3}`*" does rather undermine the point of the learning experience; although in fairness I suppose that does answer the literal question.